# Lead Convert & Attach to Existing Contact Overwrite E-mail

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

Found out that when a user converts a lead with an Email address of MyNew@Email.com and attaches it to a contact with an email address of MyOld@Email.com -- The email field isn't updated on the contact.

Is there an option or something I'm missing in the process that'll let the Contact e-mail field get updated with the new value?

Am I stuck with having to create my own Convert process in Apex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the standard process isn't doing it, you could map the lead email to a custom field on contract and use a workflow to overwrite the standard email field with the hidden custom one.

Answer (score 1):

When you convert a lead, Salesforce creates a new account, contact, and, optionally, an opportunity using the information from the lead. Any campaign members are moved to the new contact and the lead becomes read only. If an existing account and contact have the same names as those specified on the lead, you can choose to update the existing account and contact. Information from the lead is inserted only into blank fields; Salesforce does not overwrite existing account and contact data.

Check this one :https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/leads_convert.htm

So obviously a small trigger can do the job, also if you somehow clear the old data and make it blank before conversion through workflow you will be able to get to solution without lot of troubles